# How to use scipy interpn on calculated values?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a dictionary of numpy arrays, where each array is of size `(d1, d2, d3, d4)`. Each array was generated using a for loop such as the one below:

```py
for a in range(d1):
  for b in range(d2):
    for c in range(d3):
      for d in range(d4):
        array_n[a, b, c, d] = some_value
```

Consider `array_1`, `array_2`, `array_3`, and `array_4`, for example. Let's say I compute the following two new arrays:

- `array_12 = some_func_12(array_1, array_2)`
- `array_23 = some_func_23(array_1, array_3)`

Let's say given a value from `array_12` and a value from `array_23`, find me the corresponding value from `array4`.

I tried doing this with scipy's `interpn` but it doesn't work because it requires data from `array_12` and `array_23` to in ascending or descending order. While I can sort `array_12` or `array_23`, I cannot sort both of them at the same time because the act of sorting `array_12` requires `array4` to be sorted. Sorting the already sorted `array4` again with respect to `array23` will require sorting `array12` with respect to the new sorting, otherwise result will be wrong.

The question is, how do I fix this issue? Current workaround is to plotting, but this is just too slow.

Comment: what is the shape of arrays `array_12` and `array_23`? if the same as the original arrays, how do you sort 4-d arrays? also, can you be more specific regarding "corresponding value from array4"? corresponding in what way?

Comment: `array_12` and `array_23` are of size `(d1, d2, d3, d4)`.

For the second part: given a calculated valued from `array_12` and a calculated value from `array_23`, what value do they correspond to in `array_4`?

Comment: How do you order 4-D arrays? still, what does correspond mean? what is the specific relationship of the two input values and the value from `array_4`? do those values represent the index you look for? are they the closest to the value in `array_4`? as you are mentioning interpolation, do the values of `array_12` represent an input, `array_23` an output and you want to check what output the value from `array_4` would produce?